# Error al crear llave foranea en MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo las siguientes 3 tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE tEstado
  (idEstado INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Estado VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(idEstado), INDEX(idEstado))ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE tMunicipio 
   (idMunicipio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    Municipo VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    idEstado INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idMunicipio, idMunicipioEstado), 
    INDEX(idMunicipio, idMunicipioEstado), 
    FOREIGN KEY(idEstado) REFERENCES tEstado(idEstado))ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE tColonia
  (idColonia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   CP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
   Colonia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   idEstado INT NOT NULL, 
   idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(idColonia), 
   INDEX(idColonia),
   FOREIGN KEY (idEstado) REFERENCES tEstado(idEstado), 
   FOREIGN KEY (idMunicipioEstado) REFERENCES tMunicipio(idMunicipioEstado)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL)
   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Las dos primeras puedo crearlas sin ningún problema, inclusive ya tengo registros en ellas pero al momento de crear la tercera me sale el siguiente error: **Can't create table `proyecto`.`tcolonia` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")**

Agradecería mucho de su ayuda. Buenas tardes.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error de incoherencia en la tercera tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE tColonia
  (idColonia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   CP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
   Colonia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   idEstado INT NOT NULL, 
   idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(idColonia), 
   INDEX(idColonia),
   FOREIGN KEY (idEstado) REFERENCES tEstado(idEstado), 
   FOREIGN KEY (idMunicipioEstado) REFERENCES tMunicipio(idMunicipioEstado)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL)
   ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Cuando creas las columnas que formarán parte de la clave foránea (foreign key) dices que:

`idEstado INT` **`NOT NULL`**

`idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100)` **`NOT NULL`**

y cuando creas la clave foránea, dices:

`ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE` **`SET NULL`**

En la creación de la clave foránea, le dices que al borrar una columna de la otra tabla de el valor NULL a dicha columna en la tabla actual, pero eso no es posible, porque al crear la columna has pedido que la misma no admita valores nulos.

**Nota:**
Si la columna `idMunicipioEstado` ha de repetirse en dos tablas no la crearía como VARCHAR (100), sino como un entero que haga referencia en la tabla de origen (ese es el sentido de tener columnas del tipo id). Los índices serían más eficaces y reduciría considerablemente el tamaño de la BD y la posibilidad de datos erróneos, facilitando así la detección y corrección de los mismos.

En este caso, creo que desde la `tColonia`, se podría relacionar perfectamente el municipio apuntando a `idMunicipio` de `tMunicipios`. A no ser que le quieras dar otro uso no reflejado aquí, la columna `idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100)`sobra.

```
CREATE TABLE tColonia
  (idColonia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   CP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
   Colonia VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   idEstado INT NOT NULL,
```

<s>`idMunicipioEstado VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,`</s>

```
   idMunicipio INT NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY(idColonia), 
   INDEX(idColonia),
   FOREIGN KEY (idEstado) REFERENCES tEstado(idEstado),
```

<s>`FOREIGN KEY (idMunicipioEstado) REFERENCES tMunicipio(idMunicipioEstado)`</s>

```
   FOREIGN KEY (idMunicipio) REFERENCES tMunicipio(idMunicipio)...
```

Puedes echarle una ojeada a [este sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76772f/1), es un modelo parecido al tuyo, en él se va accediendo a los valores sólo por los id numéricos: con un id_municipio se puede saber perfectamente el nombre del municipio, la provincia, el estado, la colonia, el país...

Answer (score 0):

Solo para que quede claro, el error lo recibes por 2 razones:

1. Como ya explicó A. Cedano, es porque has definido una claúsula `ON DELETE SET NULL` en una clave foránea para una columna que has definido como `NOT NULL`. Esas 2 configuraciones en conjunto son incompatibles.
2. La clave foránea apunta a `tMunicipio(idMunicipioEstado)`, cuya columna no está indexada. Eso tampoco es legal.

Existen varias maneras de eliminar el error, por ejemplo agregando un índice a `tMunicipio(idMunicipioEstado)` y removiendo el `NOT NULL` a `tColonia (idMunicipioEstado)`. Pero solo porque se pueda eliminar el error, no necesariamente significa que esto sea la forma correcta de solucionarlo.

Me parece que tienes que verificar bien tu diseño, y para esto, me parece que la respuesta de A. Cedano provee muy buenas recomendaciones.